# Convert Date String Formats in Java

Tags: java, date

I am receiving Date Strings in this Format `dd-MMM-yyyy` I am intending to convert the Strings to format `yyyy-MM-dd` by trying to parse the String but I am getting an error

```
Unparseable date: 01-AUG-2014
```

I am trying to do:

```
SimpleDateFormat form new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");
String datefrom = "01-AUG-2014"
Date dfrom = form.parse(datefrom);//getting error here
```

How can I convert the String `01-AUG-2014` to `2014-08-01`?

Comment: I am not trying to Convert the String to date. I want to reformat it to a different Format but retain it as String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `dd-MMM-yyyy` use `MMM` instead for Month name to parse and than use `format` on date object you get from parsing.

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
    SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MMM-yyyy");//For parsing
    String datefrom = "01-Aug-2014";
    Date date=form.parse(datefrom);
    SimpleDateFormat myForm = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd");//for formating
    System.out.println(myForm.format(date));//new formatted String
   //String formatterDate=myForm.format(date);
```

Comment: But this will give me the date in the Same format I want the date in yyyy-MM-dd format